# How to redirect System.out to Play Logger?

Tags: java, scala, logging, playframework, logback

So I have a library that I am using in my project that uses System.out for logging and I want all of my logging to be standardized in the play logger (`play.Logger`). So, I was wondering if there is a way of redirecting the System.out to the Play Logger say at the `debug` level?
Maybe by changing System.out to use a different stream?

Notes:

My Play logger is configured to use the following appenders:

```
ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender
```

I think the library only calls `System.out.println(String)`

Answer (score 0):

Use following snippet:

```
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            if (b == '\n') {
                writeStringToActualLogger(sb.toString());
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            } else {
                sb.append((char) b);
            }
        }
    }));
```

Keep in mind that it only works with ASCII.

You have to implement `writeStringToActualLogger` to write string to your logger.